# AWS Cognito with Lambda for custom validation

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Using AWS Lambda with Cognito we can autoVerify email using below code.

```
event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
```

How can I do custom request validation here?

Like if I want to send PROMO CODE while cognito signup then can I have a code to validate this promo code and reject registration request if it is invalid promocode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working :-)

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //Auto confirming user and verifying emaail
    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
    event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
    //Extract Registration code from user attributes 
    var rCode = event.request.userAttributes["custom:rCode"];
    var validRCode = "abcdef";
    if (rCode && rCode.toLowerCase() != validRCode) {
         //If registration code is available and it is not equal to validRCode then throw error message
         var error = new Error(': Invalid registration code used.');
         context.done(error, event);
    } else {
      context.done(null, event);
    }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore. I have tested  all the appropriate triggers to try and restrict a user from signing up and there is pretty much no clean way to block a user from signing up especially if you have federated pool and using Amplify. The Cognito triggers hooks are very basic, so the only way is to ship your own API with a Lambda and Cognito through SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup triggers to customize a UserPool workflow: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html

In your case, setting up a **Pre sign-up** trigger should be fine.

Comment: I feel like from the premise of the question that Shashwat Tripathi has read that far in the docs.